# Full text index search with character at the beginning

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, sql-server-2019, string-searching

I am looking at tables like this (I did not design them):

```
CREATE TABLE EventIDsToSearch (id int not null)
insert into EventIDsToSearch  values (1)
insert into EventIDsToSearch  values (92)
insert into EventIDsToSearch  values (106)
--etc
CREATE TABLE Person (ID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,  [type] int, Notes nvarchar(1000), CONSTRAINT [PersonPK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID,[TYPE]))

insert into Person ([type], notes) values (1, 'This person is linked to Event ID 92')
insert into Person ([type], notes) values (2, 'Look at ID 67!') 
insert into Person ([type], notes) values (3, 'ID 87(3/10/15)')
insert into Person ([type], notes) values (4, '!!!187(this is the event id)')--Notice the
```

I have tried this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX PersonIndex ON Person(ID);  
    CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG ft AS DEFAULT;  
    CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON Person(Notes)   
       KEY INDEX PersonIndex   
       WITH STOPLIST = SYSTEM;
```

and I can find all the IDs except 187. For example this finds one row:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Person
WHERE CONTAINS(Notes,'92') ;
```

but this does not:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Person
WHERE CONTAINS(Notes,'187') ;
```

I believe this is because there is an exclamation mark at the beginning of 187. How can I also find 187? I am using SQL Server 2019.

I have looked here: [Using fulltext search to find a sequence of digits](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/161328/using-fulltext-search-to-find-a-sequence-of-digits).  I cannot use the LIKE operator because the performance is terrible.

Comment: I believe it is related to SQL Server 2019. I'm runnnig a **Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-GDR) (KB4583460) - 13.0.5103.6 (X64)   Nov  1 2020 00:13:28   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit)** and both queries returned a result.